# Can we use list items which are unknown, and write a function to use all the items at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of devices, which may change depending on the testbed. Here I have 4 nodes:

```
node_list = [R1,R2,R3,R4]
```

Can we write a python code to use four values at the same time while in a function.

Currently I am making it fix to a testbed:

```
R1 = node_list[0]
R2 = node_list[1]
R3 = node_list[2]
R4 = node_list[3]
```

We have a pcall function define to run concurrent calls.Let's say the function I am calling is `run_command(rtr)`:

```
pcall([run_command],iargs=[R1,R2,R3,R4])
```

Allowing all the four nodes to call run_command function at the same time. However it is fix to 4 nodes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but did you come across `map(run_command, node_list)`?

Comment: @Dr.V I would advise against using `map` to induce side-effects. Just use a for-loop.

Comment: @Dr.V: `map()` won't be concurrent. Instead, `multuprocessing.Pool.map()` will make the function calls concurrent

Answer (score 0):

You need [`multuprocessing.Pool.map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map). Details from the document:

> A parallel equivalent of the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though). It blocks until the result is ready.
>
> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.

Sample example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

p = Pool(5)
print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

will print to standard output:

```
[1, 4, 9]
```

Also, check about: [`multuprocessing.Pool.imap()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap), [`multuprocessing.Pool.map_async()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async)

Comment: The list of input you provided to the function f, can we have a dynamic list in that place. I mean here you are feeding in [1,2,3], can we have the list to be depending on output of previous function. Lets say my a() returns list [10,24,1] can I feed this one in f(x) with out manually changing the values.

Comment: I will suggest you to go through the basic tutorial related to Python, and practice with how objects work. I am passing there a list object and it could be via any source. In short, yes you may use it. In place of `[1, 2, 3]`, write `a()`